# Android ListView Text Disappears on Load

Tags: android, android-listview

When my Activity Loads on Samsung Galaxy Y and Ace Plus - mDPI/Ldpi Screens. The List View Text and Content doesnt load. On Touching and trying to scroll the Content appears.

But it works perfectly on my Development Phone Samsung S2

After some Testing i found that this is happening only on 2.X version of Android.

[image]

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
private final String[] places = new String[] { "Mysore", "Bangalore",
        "Mangalore", "Wayanad", "Bandipur National Park National Park",
        "Chickmaglur", "Bandipura", "Coorg", "Kodaikanal", "Hampi",
        "Ghati Subramanya", "Mekedatu", "Muththathhi", "Shivasamudram",
        "Talakadu", "Savana Durga" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this;

    Log.i("Nomad", "onCreate");

    List<Place> thePlaces = new ArrayList<Place>();
    for (int i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
        Place pl = new Place("NO_ID", places[i], "NO_DISTANCE",
                "NO_CATEGORYICON");
        thePlaces.add(pl);
    }

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.place_list);
    listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));

    adapter = new PlacesListAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.list_item_place, thePlaces);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.action_search);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlaceActivity.class));
        }
    });

}
```

**PlacesListAdapter.java**

```
public class PlacesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Place> implements
        Filterable {
    public Context context;
    private List<Place> orig, itemDetailsrrayList;
    private PlaceFilter filter;

    public PlacesListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public PlacesListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Place> places) {
        super(context, resource, places);
        this.context = context;
        // this.places = places;

        itemDetailsrrayList = places;
        orig = new ArrayList<Place>(itemDetailsrrayList);

        filter = new PlaceFilter();
        // imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return itemDetailsrrayList.size();
    }

    public Place getItem(int position) {
        return itemDetailsrrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        // View view = convertView;
        // Place p = places.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater viewInflater;
            viewInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = viewInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_place, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.placeTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.place_title);
            holder.placeDistance = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.place_distance);
            holder.placeCategoryIcon = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.place_category_icon);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.placeTitle.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position)
                .getPlaceTitle());
        holder.placeDistance.setText("200");
        holder.placeCategoryIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_category);

        // Setting Alternative Row Colors
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_view_place_row_1);
        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_view_place_row_2);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView placeId;
        TextView placeTitle;
        TextView placeDistance;
        ImageView placeCategoryIcon;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return filter;
    }

    private class PlaceFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<Place> results = new ArrayList<Place>();
            if (orig == null)
                orig = itemDetailsrrayList;
            if (constraint != null) {
                if (orig != null && orig.size() > 0) {
                    for (Place g : orig) {
                        if (g.getPlaceTitle()
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                            results.add(g);
                    }
                }
                oReturn.values = results;
            }
            return oReturn;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            itemDetailsrrayList = (ArrayList<Place>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}
```

**acitivty_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary_white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/place_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:fadingEdge="none" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/list_view_place_empty"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**List View Row XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/place_category_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="ss"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_category" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place_distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="320" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/place_category_icon"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Place Name"
        android:textColor="#191919"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Found this in the Logcat

```
12-23 19:58:28.033: E/ResourceType(631): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010102f3
12-23 19:58:28.083: E/ResourceType(631): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101030b
12-23 19:58:28.083: E/ResourceType(631): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101039c
12-23 19:58:28.083: E/ResourceType(631): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010103e1
12-23 19:58:31.852: E/ResourceType(631): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010102f3
12-23 19:58:31.852: E/ResourceType(631): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101030b
12-23 19:58:31.852: E/ResourceType(631): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101039c
12-23 19:58:31.852: E/ResourceType(631): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010103e1
12-23 19:58:31.934: I/Nomad(631): onCreate
12-23 19:58:32.074: I/Nomad(631): onCreateOptionsMenu
12-23 19:58:32.144: D/dalvikvm(631): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 140K, 50% free 2834K/5639K, external 2844K/2844K, paused 59ms
12-23 19:58:32.264: I/Nomad(631): after setupSearchView()
12-23 19:58:32.264: W/KeyCharacterMap(631): No keyboard for id -1
12-23 19:58:32.264: W/KeyCharacterMap(631): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
12-23 19:58:32.473: D/dalvikvm(631): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 41K, 50% free 2847K/5639K, external 3060K/3369K, paused 60ms
```

**color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="black">#333333</color>
    <color name="primary_white">#f2f2f2</color>
    <color name="dark_bg">#161616</color>

    <!-- Place List View -->
    <color name="list_view_place_row_1">#f2f2f2</color>
    <color name="list_view_place_row_2">#e7e7e7</color>
    <color name="list_view_place_selected">#CFCFCF</color>

    <!-- Place List View -->
    <color name="primary_color">#E5492A</color>
    <color name="primary_color_inverse">#c33518</color>

</resources>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Nomad Theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Nomad" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Nomad.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Nomad.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/actionbar_selectable_background</item>
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/actionbar_selectable_background</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/abs__ic_ab_back_holo_light</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/abs__ic_ab_back_holo_light</item>
        <item name="*android:actionModeShareDrawable">@drawable/ic_menu_share</item>
        <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@drawable/ic_menu_share</item>
        <item name="searchViewSearchIcon">@drawable/ic_menu_search</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Nomad.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#E5492A</item>
        <item name="background">#E5492A</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_bg</item>
        <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Can we see a bit of code please? *sly wink*

Comment: @Aelexe sorry i thought it was some silly issue and didnt need the code :D

Comment: Have you tried invalidating the layout at the end of the OnCreate? It shouldn't be needed, but it might help.

Comment: This occurs to me too. But if I set the TextSize and TextColor programmatically for the TextViews it works. You could try that.

Comment: @AndroSelva u mean to say from the Adapter right ? any idea why it happens ? also there is a Black area at the top of the List below the action bar. this is pretty wierd

Comment: please try to add this attribute to your `ListView` in your xml `android:cacheColorHint = "@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: @AndroSelva i tired doing that. Still the same problem

Comment: Can we debug this? Start by simplifying the row, try and remove the image on each row and just show the text (use an android adapter and a row layout), then if that works, use your adapter, see where the problem might be.

Comment: @Soham when i add an Image View into the Row Template this problem is occuring. Any idea how to solve it ? with only text it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Harsha I tried your code with some basic functionality and its all working fine on my Galaxy Y. May be there is some issue caused by your color.xml file. You can [download](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/79064878/BugTestListView.rar) this test project and see if it helps.

Comment: i checked the Colors.XML and cant find or think of any problem. i have included my stlyes and color xmls in the question. I tried to remove all the logic in the adapter and try again. the moment i use a Custom Adapter the content goes blank.

Comment: i think i found the problem but not able to solve it. The moment i have a ImageView in the Row XML this problem is happening in 2.X devices. its pretty wierd.

Answer (score 2):

please try to add this attribute to your ListView in your xml

```
android:cacheColorHint = "@android:color/transparent"
```

and to remove the black area, use  `android:fadingEdge="none"` in your `ListView`

Comment: fadingedge worked. but cacheColorhint doesnt help yet. still shows blank

Comment: please try to remove this line : `listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));` does it work?

Comment: and please try to modify the any `TextView` in `List View Row XML` and set the `android:textColor="@android:color/black"` ...

Comment: the setEmptyView will only be displayed when u dont have items to display and while filtering data using searchView.

Comment: oh, thats all I have, sorry.